# Python program works on Windows, but not on Linux

Tags: python, linux, shell

I know that this question has been asked before, but none of the solutions given there seemed to work for me. As the title suggests, I wrote a battleship game in python on Windows and it worked there, but when I tried to run it inside the Linux terminal, I'm getting an error I never got on Windows. [Here's the code.](https://gist.github.com/vojzzo/be14900ece315daf3c18dcd9b95aed98/)

It loads up normally, but when I input the starting position it says `NameError: name 'a0' is not defined` for example. I tried putting `!/usr/bin/python` at the beginning, but nothing changed. I'm sorry if this is a duplicate or if I'm missing something really obvious, but I would really appreciate some help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show the entire traceback for the error. It looks like you are running Python 3 in Windows and Python 2 in Linux. Check your Python versions. The `input` function behaves differently in the two versions.

Comment: not `!/usr/bin/python` but `#!/usr/bin/python` or `#!/usr/bin/env python`

Comment: It's a typo. I tried it with both `#!/usr/bin/python` and `#!/usr/bin/env python`, neither worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error seems to be in the way you are accepting input from terminal. For accepting textual data (a0, R, L, U, D etc... ) you need to use

```
raw_input()
```

in place of input. Just replace input() with raw_input() and it will work on all platforms.

Comment: Surely it will not Matthias. My answer is with respect to op's question where it is clearly stated that the error is a NameError on using input() (I went through the code) which indicates that op's machine is running Python 2.x. And yes you are right indeed another way can be to use python 3 to solve this error.